# How to access object methods from a ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I am getting a `error: 'heir' is not a member of 'Heir'` and `'heir' is not a member of 'Estate'` error in my main. I am trying to just display heir's and estate's total value using the methods `getEstateValue()` and `getHeirValue()`. Is it possible to access both methods with `Estate heir = new Heir(2000,3000)`. I have the Heir class inherit from the Estate class. Thank you for any help

below is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Estate{
    protected:
        double estateValue;

    public:
        Estate(double estateValue){
            this->estateValue = estateValue;
        }

        virtual double totalEstateValue(){
            return estateValue;
        }

        double getEstateValue(){
            return estateValue;
        }
};

class Heir:public Estate{
    protected:
        double heirValue;

    public:
        Heir(double heirValue, double estateValue):Estate(estateValue){
            this->heirValue = heirValue;
        }

        double totalEstateValue(){
            return heirValue+=Estate::estateValue;
        }

        double getHeirValue(){
            return heirValue;
        }
};

int main(){
    Estate* heir = new Heir(2000, 3000);

    //how do i access the methods in heir class? is it heir->getHeirValue?
    //how do i access the methods in the estate class? is it heir->getEstateValue?
    //here is where I am getting the error
    cout << "Heir value is: " << Heir::heir->getHeirValue() << endl;
    cout << "Estate value is: " << Heir::heir->getEstateValue() << endl;
    //here is where I am getting the error
    cout << "Total value is: " << heir->totalEstateValue() << endl;

    delete heir;
    heir = nullptr;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are calling `getHeirValue` on an `Estate*`. The `Estate` class has no function of that name. The correct answer depends on what you want to have happen when someone does this -- which we don't know. (Did you just mean `Heir *heir`?)

Comment: Maybe im confused about inheritance. Is it possible with my current code to call the methods in Heir `getHeirValue()` and also call the methods `getEstateValue` with my object `Estate heir = new Heir(2000,3000)`

Comment: Since `heir` is of type `Estate*`, it can point to an object of type `Estate`. But then you call a function, `getEstateValue` on it that is not legal to call on an object of type `Estate`. So what do you want to have happen in that case? If your answer is that that case is just impossible in the code, then change `heir` to be of type `Heir*` instead of `Estate*` to make clear that it *must* point to an `Heir` and not an `Estate`. But so long as you want to leave it possible, you have to implement it somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Variable `heir` is of type `Estate*` but points to an object of `Heir`. This is how polymorphism is expressed in C++ and legal, of course.

However, if you write `heir->getHeirValue()`, the compiler just "knows" that the object to which `heir` points is at least an `Estate`-object, and it may not rely on whether (polymorphic) `heir` actually points to an `Heir`-subclass object of `Estate` or not.

To ensure this, cast the the value of `heir` to an instance of `Heir` in order to "tell" the compiler that it may rely on the fact that `heir` points to such an object:

```
cout << "Heir value is: " << static_cast<Heir*>(heir)->getHeirValue() << endl;
cout << "Estate value is: " << heir->getEstateValue() << endl;
```

BTW: for `getEstateValue`, no such cast is needed, since `heir` is of type `Estate*`, such that objects to which `heir` point will at least be an `Estate` object and will therefore always provide the `getEstateValue`.

Comment: Thank you! `cout << "Heir value is: " << static_cast<Heir*>(heir)->getHeirValue() << endl;` fixed my issue.

Comment: You`re welcome. Don't hesitate to accept the answer if it helped you :-)